# Turn on laptop as soon as it starts charging

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, charging

Is it possible to make the laptop start up when detecting it's charging?

It has Windows 10 operating system and the laptop itself is Asus 17,3" ROG Strix GL703GM.
i have my laptop charger plugged in to remote controlled wall plug so if i could make the computer startup when the wallplug gets command to turn on i would be pleased

Comment: What do mean by "start up"? Turning itself on? Waking from sleep? Waking from hibernation? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure why clicking the button to turn it on (if the laptop is fully off)  wouldn't work as fast as plugging in the laptop to the wall. You don't mention if the computer is in sleep mode, hibernation mode which is important to determine a solution.

Comment: I ment from complitely off to start up to windows

Comment: If you do have your wall plug on the network why not send it a wake on lan signal if it supports it?

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS on many computers there is an option to boot on power (for auto-reboot after power failure). Entering BIOS setup on boot varies by system, watch for brief message at boot to hit a key (often F1, F8, esc, or enter). Look for power options.

Comment: Thank you i will have a look

Comment: Your system should be F2 on boot for setup. See page 64 in https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/GL703GS/E14527_GL703GS_GM_V2_B.pdf